# Is it possible to use a "stylesheet" in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I'm new to `WPF`. I want to design some forms using a unique but consistent style.

Is there any way to use something like a CSS stylesheet as done in in HTML?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using a Resource dictionary. You can create a xaml file and define the default styles for buttons, combobox and other user controls.

Read more about [Resource dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952(v=vs.95).aspx) at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952(v=vs.95).aspx